# Can we use FluentWait for hours selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2

Actually I am working on one script in my application there I need to wait till its complete the execution, once complete the execute it will change the status. But I don't know when the execution completes (Dynamic time).

This is web-based application and I am not sure which wait or feature or method I need to use to wait until it satisfy the condition. Below is the sample code I tried (Can not post exact code).

**Please suggest me how to proceed with or any suggestion on this.**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class TestingClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\SeleniumClass\\src\\libs\\geckodriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("https://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows/");
         
         FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
         wait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofHours(5));
         wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
         
         Function<WebDriver, Boolean> function = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>()
         {
         public Boolean apply(WebDriver arg0) {
         WebElement element = arg0.findElement(By.id("tabButton"));
         String type = element.getAttribute("type");
         System.out.println("The type is " + type);
         if(type.equals("button"))
         {
         return true;
         }
         return false;
         }
         };
         
         wait.until(function);
         }
}
```

Comment: Let us know how it went after 5 hours. :D

Comment: @MateMrše: Will see if anyone reply.

Comment: Upvote for this @Selenium

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium Webdriver has all kinds of timeouts, waiting for 5 hours isnt going to work like this. I might try something like:

1. Start browser with WebDriver and do some actions
2. Quit browsers
3. Create a while loop that waits a while (e.g. sleep a couple of minutes), then starts the a NEW browser, check if done, if not quit browser and repeat wait.

e.g. dont use Selenium todo the waiting, but your code and keep building a new session and use it only for a short while

Answer (score 1):

Explicit wait is already available for most cases:

```
WebDriverWait explicit = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofHours(5));
explicit.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")));
```

you can use expected conditions in that :

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

if you want to use special condition then use :

```
package test_suites;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Utils.excelParcer;
import driversetup.TestBaseClass;
import page_objects.homepage;

public class Testcase1 extends TestBaseClass {

    homepage homepage;
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test(description = "Test case 1 assert True")
    public void loginPageTitleTest2() {
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        // options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files
        // (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\prave\\Downloads\\msedgedriver.exe");

        driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
        FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
        wait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofHours(5));
        wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
        WebDriverWait explicit = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofHours(5));
        explicit.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")));

        wait.until(this.attributeContains(By.xpath("//button"), "type", "button"));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    

    static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> attributeContains(final By locator, final String attribute, final String value) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            private String currentValue = null;

            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(locator).getAttribute(attribute) == value;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("value found by %s to contain \"%s\". Current value: \"%s\"", locator, value,
                        currentValue);
            }
        };
    }
    


}
```

**Note**: attributeContains is already available in selenium expected condition the code is just to show you how to create your on fluent wait and expected condition